# 3CX Snom 300 auto-provisioning for idle_cancel_key_action

Tags: voip, provisioning, 3cx

I'm using a 3CX v12 phone system and I would like to add to the Snom 300 provisioning template so that the Cancel button is mapped to RETRIEVE. From the web interface of the phone I can see that the setting is for "**idle_cancel_key_action!: keyevent**" and I'd like to change it to "**F_RETRIEVE**" in the provisioning template. But when I look at the current template in order to edit it, I don't see where that setting is.

I can change it on each phone using the web interface, but I'd like to automate it using the provisioning template.

What can I add to the template so that this is done during provisioning, and where in the template do I add it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I added this at the bottom (but still inside) the *phone-settings* tag:

```
<idle_cancel_key_action perm="">keyevent F_RETRIEVE</idle_cancel_key_action>
```

That worked perfectly. I hope this may help others in the future.

Jono